# Laptop freezes after lifting the screen up

Tags: laptop, freeze

Each time that I close the laptop and after I lift up to continue with my work, it freezes with a black screen(either the leds of my mouse doesn't light up).
In the partition of windows all works perfectly, I tried to switch the driver to the proprietary but nothing good happens...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My OS is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and my graphic card is a amd/ati Kaveri R6/R7 and my laptop is a lenovo

Answer (score 0):

more info needed, but you can  try this as a meantime solution,  my fathers lap had the same problem  he was using KDE, and the problem was simply the  graphic card driver, which causes almost a complete freeze of the system; so i would try in the meantime to disable the suspend and go sleep options  ( u do this on  the options  "monitor","screen" and  in the configuration ) cant give ya more details about the names cause  y work my Ubuntu in Spanish.

> but i insist  which GUI(kubuntu,unuti,xubuntu,etc) you using and the version

Comment: I just realized I forgot to put some information, I put it all as a comment on my post